# How to create an object of an objective-C class and initialize it in SwiftUI?

Tags: object, swiftui

How can I achieve what the following code achieves in SwiftUI?

```
    Class *object = [[Class alloc] initWithNibName:@"nibname" bundle:nil];
```

Creating a constant with a type class is obviously not working without initialization:

```
    let objectName : myClass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set up Objective-C/Swift bridge correctly then just add

```
#import "myClass.h"    // your class header in YourProject-Bridging-Header.h
```

and use in .swift as in following example

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let objectName = myClass(nibName: "nibname", bundle: nil)

    // ... other code
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure that import is needed? I think I was able to manage getting the result without it. Couldn't test it yet but the compiler hasn't flagged any error since.